# На карте при наведении курсором на блок меняется местоположение метки?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

Добрый день, подскажите как правильно реализовать то, что на картинках. При наведении на блок, на карте меняется местоположение метки. У меня есть таблица `city` и там есть колонки: долгота и широта, относящиеся к каждому городу. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переход (наведение) на другой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код, где Вы пытаетесь это реализовать, что не получается?

Comment: у меня нету кода, я не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: Google maps api вам в помощь. В документации найдете необходимые методы как инициализировать карту и проставить маркеиы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данных много то ловите событие через document.getElementsByClassName и там смотрите какой вызывается сейчас DIV по его id.
Данные можете сформировать заранее и передать массивом, либо в JS получайте их через ajax.

```
<?php
//Данные из БД
$locations = [
[62.03, 129.74],
[62.04, 129.75],
[62.05, 129.76]
];
?>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ru" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //Загружаем карту в Html
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(62.0236, 129.7318),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        //Создаем маркер в позиции объекта
        var marker;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(62.0236, 129.7318),
            map: map
        });

        //Ловим нажатие мышки по карте
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            var lat = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4);
            var lng = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
            //Двигаем курсор на карте
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        });

    </script>

<div id="object1">Тут блок 1</div>
<div id="object2">Тут блок 2</div>
<div id="object3">Тут блок 3</div>

<script>
//Можете создать через цикл если данных немного
document.getElementById("object1").addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$locations[0][0]?>,<?=$locations[0][1]?>));
});
document.getElementById("object2").addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$locations[1][0]?>,<?=$locations[1][1]?>));
});
document.getElementById("object3").addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$locations[2][0]?>,<?=$locations[2][1]?>));
});
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо, вроде понимаю как мне реализовать.... а вы не скажете как сделать так чтоб при наведения не только курсор двигался а еще и карту за ним???

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
Почитайте, там написаны все методы, свойства и события для карты.

Добавьте к вашим маркерам это
map.setOptions({center: new google.maps.LatLng(62, 129)});

Comment: сделал вот так, но так не работает
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                var lat = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4);
                var lng = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
                //Двигаем курсор на карте
                marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
                marker.setOptions({center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)});
            });

Comment: click - Нажатие, для наведения мыши используйте "mousemove"

Comment: а где это прописывать надо?? я js плохо знаю, сможете помочь???

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) в этой строке замените второе значение на mousemove вместо click.

Comment: да работает, я вам кажись неправильно объяснил, при на ведения на мышкой на блок <div id="object1">Тут блок 1</div> на карте появляется маркер с нужными координатами, все работает, но карта не двигается  на координаты

Comment: document.getElementById("object1").addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$locations[0][0]?>,<?=$locations[0][1]?>));
 marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$locations[0][0]?>,<?=$locations[0][1]?>));
});

Comment: вы вначале давали такой код, он у меня есть вот пример сайту как у них реализовано  с картой https://doc.ua/doctors/kiev/all/gastroenterolog

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n9sHjfS8
только получите google key api
если непонятно всё равно то пишите в вк, там ID как тут ник

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек, у меня все заработало)

Answer (score 2):

Делайте JS событие наведения на блок. Там можете через ajax получить данные с бд широты и долготы.  Потом можно задать новое местоположение маркера:

```
function changeMarkerPosition(marker) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 130);
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}
```

Вот посмотрите в документации всё есть.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: а вы можете показать пример, как это все обернуть в html, я просто не совсем понимаю как мне это реализовать. Заранее спасибо